# Android : How to disable one item in AlertDialog with MultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, checkbox

I create a dialog with following code :

```
final CharSequence[] items        = {" One ", " Two ", " Three "};

AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title1")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, null)
            .setPositiveButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.e("1k", "count : " + ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getChildCount());

                }
            }).show();
    ListView lw = dialog.getListView();
    //lw.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(false);
    Log.e("1k", "count : " + lw.getChildCount());
```

This creates a dialog.
When I click on the "CLOSE" button I can see an output of "3" in the logs.
So far so good, "items" array has 3 Strings in it.

The last line of code, which gets invoked *after* "show()", gives me "0" in the logs.

What I want to do is disabling the first item in the list, but this code throws a NullPointerException because "getChildAt(0)" returns null :

```
dialog.getListView().getChildAt(0).setEnabled(false);
```

How can I disable the first Item in the dialog's list ?

(and why does getChildCount() ..

.. return 0 instead of 3 when invoked after show() ?

.. return 3 as expected in onclick of PositiveButton ? )

Comment: instead `setMultiChoiceItems` use `setAdapter` ... in your adapter implementation override `ListAdapter` interface ...

Comment: I tried this, but the look and feel wasn't native, even when using android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice as the layout (which is not the material one, I guess; the views were way too big. Even if I'd find the right layout used by Lollipop+ it wouldn't be forward compatible)

Answer (score 0):

See if below code helps:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    arrayAdapter.add("One");
    arrayAdapter.add("Two");
    arrayAdapter.add("Three");


AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Title1")
        .setPositiveButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();

dialog.setAdapter(
            arrayAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                    // no event on first position
                    if (position!= 0) {
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: But this way item1 would still be enabled, and I have to disable the first item in the list to indicate that item1 is included but the user can't change it.